# The process cannot access the file 'D:\....\Excel.xls' because it is being used by another process. c# web app

Tags: c#, excel, process, excel-2010, iis-express

in debug mode work fine without error

and when published web app using iis  this error appear

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:.......\Excel.xls' because it is being used by another process.

i used this code

```
   if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string excelfile=string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/temp/"+FileUpload1.FileName));

            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(excelfile);

            OleDbConnection oleDbcon=new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+excelfile+";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
            OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand("select * from [sheet1$]",oleDbcon);
            OleDbDataAdapter objAdaptor1=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            oleDbcon.Open();
            DbDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string con_str=@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert =new SqlBulkCopy(con_str);
            bulkInsert.DestinationTableName="test";
            bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
            oleDbcon.Close();
            Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles((Server.MapPath("~/temp/"))),File.Delete);
            Label1.ForeColor=Color.Green;
            Label1.Text="Successfully Inserted";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.ForeColor =Color.Red;
            Label1.Text="please select the file";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Two requests trying to use the same file at the same time?

Comment: how can i solve it ?

Comment: What line of the posted code throws the exception?

Comment: error in this line
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(excelfile);